# A pointer to the array in a struct

Tags: arrays, sorting, pointers, struct, qsort

**The first parameter of qsort requires a pointer to the array ...
How could I pass the pointer in this case?**

```
typedef struct apData {
  char ssid[32];
  sint8 rssi;
  AUTH_MODE authmode;
  char bssid[18];
  int32_t channel;
  uint8 is_hidden;
} AP;

//BSSs SCANNED
typedef struct {
  bool scanInProgress = NOT_SCANNING;
  AP **apData;
  int numAPs;
} Scan;
static Scan scanAPs;
```

...

**The problem is here in passing the first parameter ...
I don't understand why I'm getting trash in the compareRSSI() function**

`qsort(scanAPs.apData, scanAPs.numAPs, sizeof(struct apData), compareRSSI);`

...

````
int compareRSSI(const void *bss1, const void *bss2) {
  int firstAP = ((struct apData *)bss1)->rssi;
  int secondAP = ((struct apData *)bss2)->rssi;

  return (secondAP - firstAP);
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing to `qsort` a pointer to an array of **pointers** (`apData` is of type `AP**`), but you're saying that each element of the array is `sizeof(struct apData)` (as if it were an array of **structures**).  So which is it?

You didn't show how you assigned `scanAPs.apData` a value, and you didn't show where you allocated storage for the elements of the array to be sorted. So, unfortunately, it's unclear if you intended to be sorting an array of pointers or if you intended to have an array of `apData` structures.

#### If the type declaration is correct and you have an array of pointers...

Since the type of `apData` is `AP **`, then you would have had an array of pointers to structures somewhere.  In which case your sort call should have looked like:

```
qsort(scanAPs.apData, scanAPs.numAPs, sizeof(struct apData*), compareRSSI);
```

Note that the sizeof indicates that each element of the array is a pointer.

#### If the type declaration is wrong and you have an array of structures...

If it's the type that is wrong, then you need to change the type of apData to just `AP*`, and set it equal to the pointer to the first structure in the array.  You'll need to assign an appropriate value somewhere and verify that you allocated storage for the array correctly too.

Do **not** use a C-style cast when assigning `apData` a value because the compiler will ensure that you have the right type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's, **My solution**! these guys helped me a lot.
[**link**](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/172854-qsort-array-chars-nested-struct.html)!

```
qsort(scanAPs.apData, scanAPs.numAPs, sizeof(struct apData*), compareRSSI);
```

...

```
int compareRSSI(const void *bss1, const void *bss2) {
  struct apData **firstAP = (struct apData **)bss1;
  struct apData **secondAP = (struct apData **)bss2;
  return ((*secondAP)->rssi - (*firstAP)->rssi);
}
```